# How can I convert a Varchar date to an actual Date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field that is datatype = varchar(50) and I have a few different date formats like this:

```
2019-06-17
01/11/19
2019-08-21
08/04/13
10/03/17
11/22/08
2018-06-07
```

I added a new field to the table and the data type = date.  How can I convert all the dates in the varchar(50) field to actual dates in the date field?

I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
update TBL_MULTI_LD_Balance_HIST
set [actual_date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 110)

update TBL_MULTI_LD_Balance_HIST
set [actual_date] = CAST([Date] as Date)
```

But now I'm getting this error: 'Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: _Columns_, not _fields_...

Comment: SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If those values are all different formats, how are you going to convert `08/04/13`?  8th April or 4th August?

Comment: Unless you know the exact format used in each and every date, you can't simply apply a batch process to them. Some would convert under some format and fail on another. Begin by normalizing the values to a well-known format.

Comment: The others are right, considering you have mixed formatting, you can't do this automatically; not unsure you make assumptions. And even then, you can't guarantee those assumptions are going to be correct. For example `'01/02/03'` could be `'2003-02-01'` or `'2003-01-02'` or even `2001-02-03'`. Do you therefore always assume it's the format `MM/dd/yy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL_MULTI_LD_Balance_HIST
WHERE ISDATE([date]) = 0
```

This will give you a list of the ones that are giving you problems. You could then manually fix those and run your original update afterwards. This isn't fullproof but will at least give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, it is as simple as you suggest because SQL Server is pretty flexible in conversion to dates.  But some things cannot be converted.  Instead of `cast()` use `try_cast()` or `try_convert()`:

```
update TBL_MULTI_LD_Balance_HIST
    set [actual_date] = try_cast([Date] as Date);
```

Before doing this, you can get the values that don't convert by doing:

```
select [date]
from TBL_MULTI_LD_Balance_HIST
where try_cast([Date] as date) is null;
```

If all the values match your formats, then you wouldn't have a problem.  The `cast()` would just work.  That is not the case, so there is no good solution in pre-2012.  You can try:

```
update TBL_MULTI_LD_Balance_HIST
    set [actual_date] = (case when [date] like '[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]'
                              then cast([Date] as Date)
                              when [date] like '[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]'
                              then cast([Date] as Date)
                         end);
```

Obviously, this can still get bad matches, such as April 34, but those are not usually the problem in this situation.  People put in some string like "none".

Comment: @Lamu . . . I think that tag was added while I was answering.

Comment: *LaRNu*. I added in the tag for the OP, however, they had made the comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a simple CASE.  **However,** you have ambiguous dates such as `01/11/19` ... assuming `MDY` this will convert to `2019-01-11`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50),Date date )
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2019-06-17',null)
,('01/11/19',null)
,('2019-08-21',null)
,('08/04/13',null)
,('10/03/17',null)
,('11/22/08',null)
,('2018-06-07',null)
,('Not a Date',null)
,('2017-31-31',null)

Update @YourTable 
  set [Date] = case when IsDate(SomeCol)=0 then null else convert(date,SomeCol) end

Select * from @YourTable
```

**Updated Table**

```
SomeCol     Date
2019-06-17  2019-06-17
01/11/19    2019-01-11
2019-08-21  2019-08-21
08/04/13    2013-08-04
10/03/17    2017-10-03
11/22/08    2008-11-22
2018-06-07  2018-06-07
Not a Date  NULL
2017-31-31  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace all /,-  and adopt the same format for all dates, and then convert.

Comment: It turned out to be a 'US1000001' record in the date field that was throwing it off.  I deleted that record and everything worked fine.  I wonder why SQL Server doesn't suggest a more descriptive error message.  The software basically knew what the error was, but the error message was very vague.